# Updating NativeScript 6.5.1 to 8.2 : build errors when migrating from native script 6.5.1 to native script 8.2

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, node-modules

> When i do the build  "tns debug ios --env.aot" i get below build errors

ERROR in ./node_modules/nativescript-orientation/orientation.js 16:11-51
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/ui/core/view' in '/Users/admin/project/node_modules/nativescript-orientation'

ERROR in ./node_modules/nativescript-orientation/orientation.js 17:15-60
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base' in '/Users/admin/project/node_modules/nativescript-orientation'

ERROR in ./node_modules/nativescript-orientation/orientation.js 18:12-48
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/ui/enums' in '/Users/admin/project/node_modules/nativescript-orientation'

ERROR in ./node_modules/nativescript-orientation/orientation.js 19:12-48
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/ui/frame' in '/Users/admin/project/node_modules/nativescript-orientation'

ERROR in ./node_modules/nativescript-orientation/orientation.js 20:11-51
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/ui/page' in '/Users/admin/project/node_modules/nativescript-orientation'

i think these errors are due to the outdated package ,or am i missing anything?

"nativescript-orientation": "2.2.5"

this is orientation.js

[image]

in the nativescript 8.2 everything is moved to @nativescript/core and there is no tns-core-modules.
Any idea how can i make this work with the native script new version?

> Package.json

```js
{
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "8.0.0-beta.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.2.0",
    "base-64": "^0.1.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "nativescript-appversion": "1.4.4",
    "@nativescript/camera": "5.0.10",
    "nativescript-couchbase": "1.0.18",
    "@nativescript/email": "2.0.5",
    "@nativescript/geolocation": "8.0.2",
    "nativescript-orientation": "2.2.5",
    "nativescript-phone": "3.0.3",
    "nativescript-screen-orientation": "2.0.0",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.4",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.4.0",
    "utf8": "^3.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.5",
    "@nativescript/core": "~8.2.0",
    "@nativescript/angular": "^13.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.2.0",
    "@nativescript/ios": "8.2.1",
    "@nativescript/schematics": "~0.5.0",
    "@nativescript/types": "~8.2.0",
    "@nativescript/webpack": "5.0.6",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "~13.2.0",
    "typescript": "~4.5.5"
  },
  "readme": "NativeScript Application",
  "main": "./src/main.ts"
}
```

> tsconfig.json

```js
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "esnext",
        "target": "es2017",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "noEmitHelpers": true,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
       "skipLibCheck": true,
       "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
        "lib": [
            "dom",
            "es2017"
        ],
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "~/*": ["src/*"],
            "@/*": ["src/*"]
          },
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "removeComments": false
    },
    "include": [ "src/**/*.ios.ts"],
    "files": ["./src/main.ts", "./reference.d.ts"],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "platforms"
    ]
}
```

> webpack.config.js

```js
const webpack = require("@nativescript/webpack");

module.exports = (env) => {
    webpack.init(env);
    return webpack.resolveConfig();
};
```

Comment: nativescript-orientation is now available for a fee from https://proplugins.org.  There's also also https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-orientation-free/.  When I migrated my app from 6.5 to 8.1 I had to migrate a few plugins myself.  Good luck!

Comment: Hi,i tried using the nativescript-orientation-free but still getting ERROR in ./node_modules/nativescript-orientation-free/orientation.js 19:11-51 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/ui/page' in '/Users/admin/Development/project/node_modules/nativescript-orientation-free', i see the nativescript-orientation-free is still referring to tns-core-modules how did you resolve that in native script?

Comment: I responded to your SO post on the subject.  You'll likely have to migrate the plugin yourself.  My project is JavaScript, not Angular, so there will likely be some differences in the migration requirements.  It took me 3 months to migrate my app, but I was also revising the UI and upgrading to theme 3.x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by removing the third party plugin and setting it like this

```js
UIDevice.currentDevice.setValueForKey(currentOrientation, "orientation");
```